# preventing keyboard from moving view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uisearchbar

I have an hidden View on top of another view that has a search bar in it. When a button is pressed the view slides down to the screen. now, if I press the search bar, the view just moves back to its original place.
Help?

the code that does the moving:

```
_FilterViewYPosition = _FilterView.frame.origin.y;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    _FilterView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,44, _FilterView.frame.size.width, _FilterView.frame.size.height);
}];
```

the search bar itself is not connected to anything in the code at the moment, and is only exists in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your animation you are positioning `_FilterView` by its `frame`. But this view is positioned by constraints, because of auto layout. So when you use the search bar, layout takes place, and the constraints take over. You have not changed the constraints, so they conflict with the `frame` — and they win. Hence the jump back to the original position.

The solution is: to animate the position of this view, animate a change in its *constraints*, not its `frame`.

Comment: cancelling autolayout seems to prevent this from happening so you are right. can you give an explanation to the noob how this is done with constraints? thank.

Comment: Can you try doing a search? This has been covered thoroughly many times here on Stack Overflow.